# c programming if else statements

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am just starting to learn how to code in c language, my if-else statements/operators do not work. may I ask for help and show me where the error is? It does not follow the command of else and negative signs don't show too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float e1, e2, e3, n1, n2, n3, r1, r2, r3, d1, d2, d3;

    printf("Enter values in cm\n");

    printf("\nEnter eye distance for image 1:");
    scanf("%f", &e1);

    printf("Enter nose-chin distance for image 1:");
    scanf("%f", &n1);

    printf("Enter eye distance for image 2:");
    scanf("%f", &e2);

    printf("Enter nose-chin distance for image 2:");
    scanf("%f", &n2);

    printf("Enter eye distance for image 3:");
    scanf("%f", &e3);

    printf("Enter nose-chin distance for image 3:");
    scanf("%f", &n3);

    r1 = e1 / n1;
    printf("\nRatio for image 1 = %.2f", r1);

    r2 = e2 / n2;
    printf("\nRatio for image 2 = %.2f", r2);
    r3 = e3 / n3;
    printf("\nRatio for image 3 = %.2f \n", r3);

    if (r1 > r2)
        d1 = r2 - r1;
    else
        d1 = r2 - r1;
    if (r1 > r3)
        d2 = r1 - r3;
    else
        d2 = r3 - r1;
    if (r2 > r3)
        d3 = r2 - r3;
    else
        d3 = r3 - r2;

    printf("\nAbsolute difference between image 1 and image 2= %.2f", d1);
    printf("\nAbsolute difference between image 1 and image 3= %.2f", d2);
    printf("\nAbsolute difference between image 2 and image 3= %.2f", d3);

    (d1 < d2 && d1 < d3) ?
    printf("\nBest match is between images 1 and 2") :
    (d2 < d1 && d2 < d3) ?
    printf("\nBest match is between images 1 and 3") :
    (d3 < d2 && d3 < d1) ?
    printf("\nBest match is between images 2 and 3."):

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Your `if (r1 > r2)` has the same statement `d1 = r2 - r1;` on both the `if` and `else` branches; that's probably a mistake?  Anyway you could avoid all of those by using the standard `fabsf` function to compute absolute value.

Comment: And your decision near the end to use nested ternary `? :` operators to make the decision makes it very hard to read and understand.  I suggest rewriting with appropriately nested and indented `if/else`.

Comment: Also, when something basic (like `if/else`) doesn't seem to be working, it's best to pare away other complications (like user input) until either you arrive at a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or the bug jumps out at you.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(option)
{

}
else if(option)
{

}
else
{

}
```

1 Option: if

2 Option: if + else

3/more Option: if + else if + else if + else if + else

If you have more than one option the else always comes at the end